# Manipulate pandas dataframe based on values in column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe as follows, with four columns. How would one trim the dataset based on  the values in fourth column. The fourth column header is "isValid"

Input:

```
      X     Y    I  isValid
    -60.3 -15.63 25 1
    -60.2 -15.63 10 1
    -60.1 -15.63 0 0
    -60.0 -28.23 0 0
    -59.8 -28.23 25 1
    -59.7 -28.23 15 1
    -59.7 -28.23 0 1
```

Output - 1 :

```
X    Y     I
-60.3 -15.63 25 
-60.2 -15.63 10 
-59.8 -28.23 25 
-59.7 -28.23 15 
-59.7 -28.23 0
```

Edit: I was able to achieve Output 1, by using something as follows:

```
df = df.loc[df['isValid'] == 1]
```

Output 2:

For a given value in second column, average the third column values.

```
   Y      I
 -15.63 (25+10)/2 
 -28.23 (25+15)/2
```

I am presently converting everything into numpy arrays and working with loops. Hoping there is a much simpler way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Right after I asked the question, I figured that out. However, the process to get output 2 is still a mystery for me.

Comment: What are your column headers for this dataframe?

Comment: Added the headers

Comment: @Jesh Kundem this looks like spatial data. You cant handle coordinates like you are suggesting. Averaging on a latitude or longitude cant make the data meaningful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

dfm = df[df['isValid'] == 1]

df_out = dfm.groupby('Y', as_index=False)['I'].mean()
```

Output:

```
       Y     I
0 -28.23  20.0
1 -15.63  17.5
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Scott. I believe I missed one aspect. Which is there are zero values in 'I' column, and they should not averaged. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @JeshKundem dfm does eliminate the isValid == 0.  Hence, the mean of I is calculated with out the isValid equal to zero.  dfm is a filter version of df where isValid equals to 1.  Then I am using dfm to calculate mean, therefore isValid equals to zero are not considered in the average calculation.

Comment: @ Scott Boston - I mean the Zero values in "I" column. However I am accepting the answer, as I was able to eliminate them by adding another criteria df['I']!=0

Comment: @JeshKundem Thanks.   Happy Coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.